# Hide The iPad Keyboard By Hitting the Return Key

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, ios, keyboard

Is it possible to hide the iPad keyboard after entering a value into an input field on a website by hitting the <kbd>Return</kbd> key without forcing the user to use the <kbd>Hide Keyboard</kbd> key?

Is there something in HTML or jQuery that I can code into my page to force this behavior?

(P.S. Based of my hours of research online, it seems impossible with the way the iPad currently functions. But I would really appreciate any info!)

Comment: Also, how come the iPad keyboard does not disappear when touching an area outside of the keyboard like on the iPhone? Is there a way to get around that as well?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can hide the keyboard by calling the `blur` handler on the text input:

```
$("#textField").blur();
```

where `#textField` is a selector to select the text input. You need to put this line in the right place, which depends on how the form is coded, and in most cases would be in the form's submit handler.

Comment: +1 this works. Just make sure to fire the .blur() event on all possible input elements on the page, and it should work like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest answer to your question on any input regardless of form submit would be

```
$('input').keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      $(this).blur();
    }
});
```

Probably a little easier to put in the right place.

Return = Enter key

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're after

[How do I cancel a text field edit in a UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792035/how-do-i-cancel-a-text-field-edit-in-a-uiwebview)

Comment: Just want to make sure that everyone here understands this is just a plain HTML and CSS webpage with a little bit of jQuery. Not a native app using the SDK....This solution will work for that, right? what is UIWebView? is that jQuery syntax? (I am a slight noob with Javascript)

Comment: UIWebView is the iOS construct that allows you to display web content in your iPad or iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `resignFirstResponder` on the text field.  That should dismiss the keyboard.  I know this works on iPhone, and don't know of a reason it wouldn't on iPad, though I don't recall having tried that specifically on that platform.

Comment: the OP is not actually using a UITextField so this approach won't work. Assuming it is a text field embedded in a UIWebView it will need to be done using javascript. I have posted a link to a similar question in my answer.

Comment: Ah, good point!  Sorry, I guess I didn't read the question carefully enough.  :/